# Wpf как сделать чтобы Textbox не растягивался когда текст достигает границы контента

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть Textbox, если ставить фиксированный размер, то `TextWrapping="Wrap"` если текст достигает границу Textbox по ширине, то текст переносится на новую строку. Но мне нужна привязка размера ширины к Grid, но в этом случае текст растягивает Texbox по ширине. Подскажите как исправить такое.

```
     <Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid Background="Gray">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="55"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Border Margin="14 14 7 0" Height="44" CornerRadius="6" Background="White">
                    <Label FontSize="14" Margin="14 0 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Text" Foreground="#3B454A" Padding="0" FontFamily="Gilroy" FontWeight="Medium"></Label>
                </Border>
                <Border Grid.Column="1" Margin="7 14 14 0" Height="44" CornerRadius="6" Background="White">
                    <Label FontSize="14" Margin="14 0 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Text" Foreground="#3B454A" Padding="0" FontFamily="Gilroy" FontWeight="Medium"></Label>
                </Border>
                <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="14 14 7 0" Background="#FFFFFF" Height="167" CornerRadius="6">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ScrollViewer Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0"  Margin="0,0,0,64" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                            <TextBox   AcceptsReturn="True" Margin="0 0 18 0"  TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="14" ></TextBox>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                        <Button  Height="36" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="14 0 3.5 14" Content="Добавить файлом"></Button>
                        <Button  Grid.Column="1" Height="36" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="3.5 0 14 14" Content="Очистить"></Button>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="7 14 14 0" Background="#FFFFFF" Height="167" CornerRadius="6">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBox Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  FontSize="14" Margin="0,0,0,64"></TextBox>
                        <Button  Height="36" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="14 0 3.5 14" Content="Добавить файлом"></Button>
                        <Button  Grid.Column="1" Height="36" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="3.5 0 14 14" Content="Очистить"></Button>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <Border Grid.Row="2" Margin="14 6 7 0" Background="#FFFFFF" Height="36" CornerRadius="6">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label FontSize="14" Margin="14 0 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Файл: " Foreground="#3B454A" Padding="0" FontFamily="Gilroy" FontWeight="Medium"></Label>
                        <Label FontSize="14" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Нет" Foreground="#BBBBBB" Padding="0" FontFamily="Gilroy" FontWeight="Medium"></Label>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
                <Border Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Margin="7 6 14 0" Background="#FFFFFF" Height="36" CornerRadius="6">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label FontSize="14" Margin="14 0 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Файл: " Foreground="#3B454A" Padding="0" FontFamily="Gilroy" FontWeight="Medium"></Label>
                        <Label FontSize="14" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Нет" Foreground="#BBBBBB" Padding="0" FontFamily="Gilroy" FontWeight="Medium"></Label>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
                <Border Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="14 10 14 0" Background="#FFFFFF" Height="44" CornerRadius="6">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label FontSize="14" Margin="14 0 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Настройки" Foreground="#3B454A" Padding="0" FontFamily="Gilroy" FontWeight="Medium"></Label>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148767/discussion-on-question-by-xellan-wpf----textbox---); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.